# pandas groupby by different key and merge

Tags: pandas

I have a transaction data main containing three variables: user_id/item_id/type, one user_id have more than one item_id and type_id ,the type_id is in (1,2,3,4)

```
data=DataFrame({'user_id':['a','a','a','b','b','c'],'item_id':['1','3','3','2','4','1'],'type_id':['1','2','2','3','4','4']})
ui=data.groupby(['user_id','item_id','type']).size()
u=data.groupby(['user_id','type']).size()
```

What I want to get in the end is get every user_id's amount of distinct type_id
 and also the every user_id,item's amount of distinct type_id,and merge then  by the user_id

Comment: Please post raw input data and desired output, your question is very unclear at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to answer but here is one solution:

```
import pandas as pd

data= pd.DataFrame({'user_id':['a','a','a','b','b','c'],'item_id':['1','3','3','2','4','1'],'type_id':['1','2','2','3','4','4']})

ui = data.copy()
ui.drop('item_id',axis=1,inplace=True)
ui = data.groupby('user_id').type_id.nunique().reset_index()

u = data.groupby(['user_id','item_id']).type_id.nunique().reset_index()

final = ui.merge(u,on='user_id',how='inner').set_index('user_id')
final.columns = ['distinct_type_id','item_id','distinct_type_id']

print final
```